# Propagate events in several layers android google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I'm developing a google maps based application for android 1.6.

My problem is that in my application I have more than one layer that extends from ItemizedOverlay representing information in the map.

The problem is that all the layers implement the onTap method, but now only the last layer (on the top of the stack) detects the tap event, so If the user taps on an item that is in a deeper item the method onTap never fires.

Is there any way to propagate the event to deeper layers?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed since android 2.0, it was a known issue of some phones including mine (MyTouch3G)